# I have to install the sources for gpsd and I meet this error, what to do?

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, gpsd

Here are the error messages even though I have installed the python modules ( serial , matplotlib ... ) when I type the command :
scons && scons check && scons udev-install

```
WARNING: gpsplot is missing required runtime module matplotlib
WARNING: ubxtool and zerk are missing optional runtime module serial
Ensure your PYTHONPATH includes /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/
```

Comment: Did you ensure, that your PYTHONPATH includes /usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the clue building gpsd.

Aw bad are messages to explain errors.. I did understand by reading the Sconscript

So to get the package just do

`<sudo> apt install -y python3-matplotlib`

then be explicit calling scons

`scons target_python=python3`

if you do not specify python version it uses by default python and so it will not find matplotlib (which is said by the error message gpsplot).

And same for QtNetwork it did not find because the pkgFind script was not able to get the version by itself, so you have to be explicit. I installed Qt5.

`scons qt_versioned=5 target_python=python3`

`scons -h # minus`

to see gpsd build options

I hope it helped

Comment: the result is to get

`Checking Python module matplotlib... found`
instead the error, after that I am no more required to explicit target_python o_O

Comment: in the scons command you have to give also the python lib dir, otherwise the curreent 
pythonpath
you can set as `python_libdir=$(find /usr/local/lib/python* -name dist-package| tail -n1)`